# What's the meaning of Redis `hdr`?

Tags: redis

In Redis, the Simple Dynamic String (SDS) can be implemented with `sdshdr8`、`sdshdr16`、`sdshdr32`, etc. So what's the meaning of "hdr"? High Dynamic Range ?

Comment: It's short for *HEADER*

Comment: Also, the number stands for the log of maximal string length a header is associated with. So hrd8 will be associated with short strings of up to 256 bytes and so on.